# Ancestry gem says "undefined method `ancestry' for..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, tree, ancestry

I have installed **ancestry gem**, in gemfile:

```
gem "ancestry", "~> 2.0.0"
```

In model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :..., :name, :..., :ancestry, :..., :...
  #acts_as_tree
  has_ancestry cache_depth: true
  has_many :cars
end
```

And when I load in a view the respective category:

```
- category = Category.where('my_category_id = ?', @game.car_category_id)
%div= category.inspect
```

The output is

```
[#<Category id: 58, name: "Name", ..., created_at: "2013-11-22 15:00:01", updated_at: "2013-11-24 14:54:06", ancestry: "7", car_category_id: 6205>]
```

So in the column **ancestry** is the value **7**.
When I try to display this value, **= category.ancestry**, the result is:

```
undefined method `ancestry' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fce5e61dcb0>
```

The same also when I try to inspect that value...

What am I doing wrong here? Why I cannot work with **ancestry** value?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get a real instance, so replace:

```
category = Category.where('my_category_id = ?', @game.car_category_id)
```

with:

```
category = Category.where('my_category_id = ?', @game.car_category_id).first
```

Btw, this should be done in your controller. Not in your view. ( and using scopes wont hurt :) )

Comment: Oh fu_k, I need some sleep. Thank you @apneadiving.